# Is it possible to get a post's markdown from SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

In SEDE (specifically, in the `Posts` table), is it possible to get the markdown for a post, i.e. what you would see if you went to the site itself and tried to edit it? Querying for `Posts.Body` only gets you the baked HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it's arguably [easier to use the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids) with a filter that includes `body_markdown`, you can grab the latest `PostHistory` entry with `PostHistoryTypeId` 2, 5, or 8 and use the `Text` field, which contains the Markdown of the post body. You can see this in action [in this example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/184219?PostId=5524065).