# HTML Tags Used in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was doing some queries on the Data Explorer and I noticed that the post `Body` is stored in HTML format instead of Markdown like I expected.  I'm interested in parsing this HTML ([obviously not with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1110928)) to convert to a different markup language.

For this parsing, it would help to know if a particular *subset* of HTML tags are used.  (i.e. `<b>` is *never* used, or something similar)  Is there a listing of such tags?

Comment: Also of interest: [Is it possible to get a post's markdown from SEDE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229925/is-it-possible-to-get-a-posts-markdown-from-sede) (Spoiler: Yes)